# How do I disable the nagging to update to High Sierra?

Tags: macos

I am on Sierra and would like to disable the periodic nagging to update to High Sierra. I will do it when I am ready. Any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Open the Folder `/Library/Bundles`
- Move the bundle named **OSXNotification.bundle** to your Desktop

Restart. If you not have any further problems you can delete this bundle.
Thanks [eclecticlight](https://eclecticlight.co/2017/11/22/are-you-being-pestered-to-upgrade-to-high-sierra/) for this hint.

Comment: Thanks - I have tried that and will report back if it does not work!

Comment: Unfortunately as of May 2nd 2018, the OSXNotification.bundle is no longer in /Library/Bundles (and no I am not looking in ~/Library/Bundles).

Answer (score 6):

There are two ways to do this. The first should just prevent the prompt to update to the newest OS while the second will disable the App Store from bothering you altogether to update anything.

The most recommended is to go to the App Store, select the Updates tab, right click on the update you wish to stop being bothered about, and select "Hide Update".

The alternative is to go to System Preferences, click on App Store, deselect "Automatically check for updates". This should prevent the App Store from bothering you about all available update.

Comment: Thanks I did this a while back but I think it is already downloaded and nags me to install. Control clicking does not do anything though and I do wish other updates.